# loop a column in datagridview to get the value?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, web-services, datagridview

i am doing a project on web service and window form
basically i meet some problem and not sure how to solve

1. i want to get the data in every row in ColA of datagridview and inside into the data base through web service, to get something like this row1;row2;row3;row4......so i did a for loop but at underline with the nominal which i highlight in bold

   ```
   private void push_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {

       string nominal;

       for (int i = 0; i < DGV.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           nominal = Convert.ToString(DGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);

       }
       WSBrand insertInto = new WSBrand();
       insertInto.Insert(**nominal**)
   }
   ```

this is my insert method

```
[WebMethod]

public DataSet Insert(String BrandName)
{

    SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand();
    dbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Brand (BrandName)VALUES (@BrandName)";
    dbCommand.Connection = conn;
    da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = dbCommand;
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BrandName", BrandName);


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: @cutexxxbabies - Please frame your question properly, so that we can answer.

Comment: i want the data of ColumnA in datagridview in every row to be insert to a database ...to get a result of row1;row2;row3....

Comment: Get the insert inside, the string will have last value from the loop

Comment: @V4Vendetta,  i try to put the insert inside , but it print out alot of time..bt is each row it self, not together

Comment: @cutexxxbabies How about using `FormattedValue` instead of `Value`

Comment: @V4Vendetta, i use what you say , the A and B is separate inserted, and it give me this result 
record 1 blank record 2 A record 3 B record 4 blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void push_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    StringBuilder nominal = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0;i<DGV.Rows.Count;i++){
        nominal.Append(Convert.ToString(DGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value) + ";");
    }
    WSBrand insertInto = new WSBrand();
    InsertInto.Insert(nominalList); 
}
```

In Your WSBrand Class:

```
    [WebMethod]
public DataSet Insert(string nominal)
{        
    SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand();
    dbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Brand (BrandName)VALUES (@BrandName)";
    dbCommand.Connection = conn;
    dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BrandName", sb.ToString());
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand dbCommand2 = new SqlCommand();
    dbCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Brand";
    dbCommand2.Connection = conn;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = dbCommand2;
    dbCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

The problem is that nominal is being overwritten in every iteration of the for loop. If you create a List of strings that contain all the values of the DGV then it will be easier to access them all in your WSBrand class.

EDIT: When you are executing the INSERT Statement the only thing that will be returned is the number of rows affected. To get all the data back you must execute a SELECT * FROM Brands query and that will enable you to fill your Dataset with data!

Final EDIT: This should work hopefully. I have changed both the push_Click method and the Insert Method. If there are any syntax errors you will have to work these out as I done this in notepad. Good Luck

Comment: the database don't show the data, it show this "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

Comment: What is your Insert Method expecting? You should change the method signature to Insert(List<string> nomList) and where you had nominally before you need to loop through the list to get each of the values. I'm not sure what you are going to do with nominal once you have put in into Insert.

Comment: so bascially this insert is a web method , i use this web method and insert to another database table, so if ColA row 1 data is D, row 2 data is E then row 3 data is F...i want to get this in the database of one the database column ..D;E;F

Comment: @cutexxxbabies So you want the string BrandName to literally be "D;E;F" of do you want to insert D, E and F into the Brand table seperately. If so, use my edit.

Comment: @stuartmclark i want it together in a record...Plus the insert is a web method why do u write it as class...cause i normally use dataset

Comment: @stuartmclark, i want "D;E;F;"

Comment: Ok, updated the edit. You need to remember to do another query to get the actual data as this query will not return the data, it will nly return the number of rows that have been inserted. Which should be 1.

Comment: @stuartmclark  where should i do  the query at?

Comment: Straight after you have done the dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery, just create another SQLcommand but with the Command Text saying "SELECT * FROM Brand" Then fill your Dataset with the returned values using the SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: @stuartmclark ...can show me, it will be much clear for me to understand

Comment: @stuartmclark when i write this  InsertInto.Insert(nominalList);  this underline the nominalList

Comment: @stuartmclark where the sb come from

Comment: @stuartmclark the dbcommand cannot double declare then how to put both in the data set

Comment: @stuartmclark where sb come from ...dataset to call the dbcommand must make any change

Comment: Sorry, take out sb.ToString() and just put nominal in.

Comment: @stuartmclark as for the dataset is there any change? cause now is different dbcommand

Comment: You should still be expecting the same data to come out so there should be no change

Comment: it prompt me with this soapExpection was unhandled

Comment: @stuartmclark, cannot, at the sentence  InsertInto.Insert(nominal); it promt me tje SoapExpection was unhandled

Comment: Put a Try ... Catch statement around InsertInto.Insert(nominal). Also you will need to create a Dataset in your push_Click method to receive the Dataset returned from Insert. i.e. try{ Dataset ds = InsertInto.Insert(nominal); } catch(Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());}

Answer (score 0):

Simply use foreach loop:

```
foreach(DataGridviewRow a in DGV.Rows)
{
 string  nominal = Convert.ToString(a.Cells[1].Value)

    WSBrand insertInto = new WSBrand();
    insertInto.Insert(nominal)

}
```

Comment: but when i use ` WSBrand insertInto = new WSBrand();
    insertInto.Insert(nominal)` the nominal is underline

Comment: try this way ...it print out alot of time, but i want to insert row 1 D row 2 E row 3 F to the another database D;E;F